# Do I have my steps right for painting over stained trim?

Tags: paint, trim, oil

I bought a 30 year old home that was a bit of a project and I'm currently updating the kitchen. All the rooms in the house have white trim except the kitchen. It has stained wood and it looks horrible, it barely had any glossy look to it.

I already cleaned it with TSP, sanded it lightly with 180 grit, and I also used a liquid sandpaper.

Here's where I need some help. I have a pregnant wife and kids at home so I'm trying to avoid using any oil based paints or primers. Can I apply a latex primer and a latex paint at this point? I'm not concerned about seeing brush strokes, I mostly want to make sure this will last.

Comment: Sure, but this is somewhat a product question, and is therefore off-topic. Visit your paint store and ask what they have for your purpose. Your preparation seems more than adequate.

Comment: Paint billed as "trim paint" or typically used for paint is usually just a gloss or semi-gloss latex paint in residential applications, in my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because "it barely had any glossy look to it" and you sanded it and cleaned it well means that it has been properly prepared! Good work.

Feel free to prime and paint it now, but do yourself a couple favors and buy good quality paint and professional grade brushes. I cannot stress how much a difference using quality applicators will make. Just build time into your schedule for thoroughly cleaning them and they will serve you well for years.